# Pavucontrol shows that audio is playing but no output heard

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a problem that has been bothering me for a week now:
I have installed debian 10 (buster)(32-bit) on an acer aspire 1610 and i am having problems with the audio card:
essentially pavucontrol tells me that sound is playing but no sound can be heard from the sink in question (my rear green jack)
The machine mounts a SIS966 audio card and an NVidia graphics card that has also audio card features (hdmi)
I couldn't care less about the NVidia card i just want the SIS card to be working
---System Information---

OS: Debian 10 buster

Desktop manager: LXDE

```
pacmd list-sinks
2 sink(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY FLAT_VOLUME DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 9030
    volume: front-left: 200 /   0% / -150.93 dB,   front-right: 200 /   0% / -150.93 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: yes
    current latency: 30.57 ms
    max request: 6 KiB
    max rewind: 6 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 40.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 1999.82 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "HDMI 1"
        alsa.id = "HDMI 1"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "7"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xfcffc000 irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0e0f"
        device.product.name = "GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller"
        device.string = "hdmi:1,1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352768"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176384"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo-extra1"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)"
        device.description = "GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Nvidia GPU 51 HDMI/DP"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10de0051,145836f9,00100100"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                device.product.name = "CVTE TV
     "
    active port: <hdmi-output-1>
  * index: 3
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0f.0.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY FLAT_VOLUME DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: yes
    current latency: 39.98 ms
    max request: 7 KiB
    max rewind: 7 KiB
    monitor source: 4
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 3
    configured latency: 40.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 1837.33 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_0f.0>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC1200 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC1200 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA SIS966"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA SIS966 at 0xfdff0000 irq 18"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:0f.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1039"
        device.vendor.name = "Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]"
        device.product.id = "7502"
        device.product.name = "Azalia Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352768"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176384"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC1200"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0888,105b0c9e,00100101"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
```

```
 cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [SIS966         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA SIS966
                      HDA SIS966 at 0xfdff0000 irq 18
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xfcffc000 irq 17
```

```
 uname -r 5.10.13
```

things that i know and that i've tried

Things that i know:

The user is in the audio group

The behaviour is present even with sudo

The tests that i've done where done with speaker-test and mpv (none working)

Things that i've tried:

Unmuted anything unmutable in the alsamixer

Changed default soundcard systemwide

Updated kernel

Uninstalled pulseaudio (and reinstalled afterwards)

Tried same tests from various live cds (manjaro/linux mint/puppy linux fossapup)

Any guesses? thanks

EDIT: [dmesg](https://pastebin.com/PEy473vi)

Edit2: pavucontrol images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: take a look at this link especially at the Troubleshooting steps https://wiki.debian.org/Sound

Comment: already did all of that and nothing worked

Comment: if you do `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec` what's the output?

Comment: i have disabled the nvidia soundcard so now the output is

Codec: Realtek ALC1200

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your pavucontrol settings?

Comment: @D'ArcyNader added screenshots

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120649/discussion-between-darcy-nader-and-overclock351).